# mkdir can not create directory, no such file or directory after installing ubuntu and removing windows

Tags: permissions, mount, filesystem, windows-10

So I recently installed ubuntu. Before this I had Windows installed with 3 drives i.e 'C:/','Studies:/' etc.

I only tried to remove the C drive and installed ubuntu there, which I did successfully. Now that Ubuntu is installed; when I opened Ubuntu I 'mounted' the 'Studies' drive. First it mounted as read only, so I changed it to write mode following google, using this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/mzali/Studies
```

But now I am getting this error when I try to create a directory or a virtual environment:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘python_env’: No such file or directory
```

Note that I also get it if I use the -p tag.
Below is the output of 'cat /proc/mounts'

```
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3991148k,nr_inodes=997787,mode=755,inode64 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=805168k,mode=755,inode64 0 0
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
bpf /sys/fs/bpf bpf rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1709 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tracefs /sys/kernel/tracing tracefs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service ramfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop2 /snap/core20/1778 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop0 /snap/core20/1587 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop1 /snap/bare/5 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop3 /snap/firefox/1635 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop4 /snap/firefox/2211 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop5 /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop6 /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop7 /snap/snapd/17883 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop9 /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop11 /snap/snap-store/638 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop8 /snap/snap-store/582 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop10 /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/sda2 /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell ext4 ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/loop12 /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/49 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/sda5 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/snapd/ns tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=805168k,mode=755,inode64 0 0
nsfs /run/snapd/ns/snapd-desktop-integration.mnt nsfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=805164k,nr_inodes=201291,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
portal /run/user/1000/doc fuse.portal rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sdb3 /media/mzali/Studies fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

I tried googling a lot, and there are a lot of answers for this issue but most of them are just to use the 'p' tag and it isn't working for me.

I switched to Ubuntu so I won't have the usual windows issues in installing different software, but this is even worse.

Comment: please provide the actual command and response for what you tried, not just the result.

Comment: @Rinzwind which command? I am trying 'mkdir anydir' but its giving the error mentioned.

The long output is for the command 'cat /proc/mounts', that is also mentioned in the question.

If you are talking about the part of 'removing the C drive', then it was during Ubuntu installation. And Ubuntu is installed now.

Comment: @Rinzwind question edited.

Comment: It's possible that you're running `mkdir` from within a directory that no longer exists. What does `pwd` say? Have you tried `cd` (without any arguments) to go back to your home directory?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini The directory exists. If it doesn't exist, the -p tag in mkdir should create it, isn't it?
Also, pwd creates the directory I am in.

All the 'drives' from my windows are mounted as external hard drives I think. Check the image: https://imgur.com/a/JkMPHaO.

The 4 'grey' icons (in image) on the left were my drives in windows.

Comment: No, even with the `-p` flag, if you're in a directory that does not exist, `mkdir` will fail (if you pass a relative path, like in your case). Also note that even after you re-create a directory with the same name, you need to `cd` back into it

Comment: I fixed it. It was an issue with the ntfs file system. For some reasons windows was not completely deleted and I had to unmount, run 'ntfsfix' and then remount it for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows was not completely deleted. Unmount the 'Studies' drive, run `ntfsfix` and then remount the 'Studies' drive for it to work.